# Project Euler 4 not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code is according to [project euler problem no.4](https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=4).

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

The expected output is `906609` but this code give the output as `994009`.

```
from array import *

def is_palindrome(num):

    a = array('i',[])
    j=0
    while(num>0):
        a.insert(j,num%10)
        num=num/10
        j+=1
    if(a[0]==a[j-1]):
        return True
    else:
        return False

a=100
b=100
max=0
c=False
while(a<=999):

    while(b<=999):
        n=a*b
        c=is_palindrome(n)
        if(c and n>max):
            max = n
        b+=1
   b=100    
   a+=1    
print(max)
```

Comment: I would suggest mentioning the problem. Atleast adding a link to it !

Comment: @Noob Sorry for that. Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `is_palindrome()` function is wrong, you are only checking if the first element is equal to the last element and returning `True` if they are equal, `False` if they are not.

```
if(a[0]==a[j-1]):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Obviously, that is wrong -

> A palindrome is a word, phrase, number, or other sequence of characters which reads the same backward or forward.

An easy solution for your is_palindrome() function is -

```
def is_palindrome(num):
    s = str(num)
    n = len(s)
    return all(s[i] == s[n-i-1] for i in range(0,int(n/2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking your palindromes :P If a palindrome reads the same in forwards and reverse, just...reverse your number.

```
def is_Palindrome(num):
    return str(num) == str(num)[::-1]
```

slicing with a step of -1 is the same as reversing.

(Also, as a generalized thing with project euler, but probably not necessary for this question specifically...when you want the largest number, don't start iterating from the bottom, start iterating from the top, and break when it's no longer possible for you to beat the current best answer)